# Linked List - Removing Last Node

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I am creating a function to remove the last node of a given list (inputted as an argument). The function itself is quite simple as shown below.

```
function popBack(list) {
    var current = list.head,
        previous;

    while (current.next) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    // console.log(current);
    // console.log(previous.next);
    // current = null;
    // console.log(current);
    // console.log(previous.next);

    previous.next = null;
    return list;
}
```

Since the next node in the list is referenced by the one before it, previous.next and current should point to the same object. This brings me to my question. If I set `current` equal to `null`, wouldn't that make `previous.next` equal to `null` as well? This doesn't seem to be the case, as `previous.next` still references what `current` used to be. Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A very common rookie mistake is to think that two variables are the same, when you change one, you change another. You have it right, though: both of them just *point at the same object*. Then one of them stops pointing. The other one is unchanged in its pointiness. If you want two variables to cease their pointing, you have to yell at both of them individually.

Comment: As Amadan said, you aren't actually deleting the object, just changing what `.next` references.

Comment: Hey Amadan, thanks so much for your prompt reply. What I took from your response is that by setting `current = null`, it stops `current` from pointing to the same object that `previous.next` is pointing to. So now `current` is pointing to a new memory bank with no value. Is this correct?

Comment: Almost but not quite. `null` is a primitive value: JS variables *refer to* objects (you could also say "contain object references", though you can't actually see them directly from JS like you can from, say, C), but *contain* primitives. Thus, "`current` points to `null`" is not correct; "`current` contains `null`" is. By virtue of containing `null`, `current` does not point anywhere any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that `previous.next` and `current` point to the same object. Let's call that object `O`. That is,

- `previous.next` points to `O`.
- `current` points to `O`.

When you run the following code,

```
current = null;
```

it doesn't set `O` to null, it only changes what `current` points to. That is, after `current = null;` is run, this is the new state:

- `previous.next` points to `O`.
- `current` points to `null`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. Your answer reinforced my response to Amadan's reply.